# Binary Hidden Markov Model

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process, bayesian-network, hidden-markov-models

Consider a binary HMM with 2 observed variables $O_n  \in \{0,1\} \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Suppose that the hidden Markov process $X_n$ is characterised by a known transition probability matrix $P$ with an also known initial distribution $\nu$. The observations $o_n$ are linked with the hidden variables $x_n$ in some way such that the emission probability matrix $B$ linking $X_n$ to $O_n$ is also known.

I was wondering if one would be able to work out a probability distribution of the number of $1$s (or zeros) in an arbitrary observation sequence $\textbf{O} = (O_1, O_2, \dots, O_n)$? I can calculate the run-time distribution but I would like to know if: $$T_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} O_i, $$ then what is: $$f_{T_n}(x) = \mathbb{P}(T_n = x)  \qquad x \in \{0, \dots, n\}$$

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You are calculating the probability distribution before actually observing any $o_n$, correct?

Comment: This can be expressed as a sum over every $X$-path of the probability of the path times the probability that this path produces observations with a given number of 1s. Thus, as is customary with HMMs, one gets sums of exponentially many terms that one cannot really do anything with. On the other hand, if only asymptotics are needed, then the result is direct using the stationary distribution of the $(X,O)$ chain.

Comment: Yes before observation, Mikkola.

Comment: Thanks Did. What is the result using the stationary distribution of the (X,O) chain? I'm not sure where to look with this; thanks :)

Comment: $$\frac{T_n}n\to\sum_{x\in X}\pi(x,1)\quad\text{almost surely and in}\ L^1.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Any textbook on Markov chains since (X,O) is just that, a Markov chain.